# only get a part of data from mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback, promise

I have a problem with using asynchrone code in nodejs with mongodb.
In my current code I am writing some mongodb data in my console. Now I want to only get the "test1" from the data I receive. I would like to only get "test1" in the console and not the whole mongodb object. How would I archive this with?

```
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
let dbo = db.db("list");
let cursor = dbo.collection('name').find({name: articleName});
let cont3nt = cursor.toArray(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
    return doc;
});
//console.log(cont3nt);
return cont3nt;
});
```

The console returns the following:

> [ { _id: 5b6bf5072a0fd912380bcb3a, name: 'test1' } ]

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You would use a projection to exclude/include only the fields you want…?! https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/ Not sure what this has to do with promises or callbacks.

Comment: How exactly would this look like in my code? I'm really dumb about this for some reason. The goal I want to archive is to use the "test1" from mongodb in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deceze suggested you could use projection.

In your example:

```
let cursor = dbo.collection('Bauteilname').find({name: articleName}, {"name":1, _id:0});
```

the `"name":1` is for returning only the name field and the `_id:0` is for not returning the _id field since it is always displayed and needs to be explicitly excluded.

source:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_projection.htm

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried doing that like deceze suggested but for some reason I still get the same result.